# How to prevent caching of asynchronous requests?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, caching

I'm working on a sortable table, that is refreshed asynchronously when the column headers are clicked. The parameters determining the column I'm sorting by and the direction are stored in the query string. The first time I click the header, the table is sorted by that column ascending, the second time it's sorted descending. But the third time i click it, the column isn't sorted in the opposite direction, as I would expect.

I am using jQuery to handle the asynchronous requests. I can see that the $.get request gets hit, and the callback function is executed when the request returns. I can see that a request is sent to the server and the HTML is returned to the page, but the breakpoints in my Action Method don't get hit.

This indicates to me that the content I want to regenerate is cached and that cached content is being returned. Is there any way for me to prevent the cached content from being returned when these column headers are clicked?

.. just to note, I don't have anything specified anywhere for OutputCaching. Is this turned on by default somehow? Could that be the culprit??

Comment: Is this just one one browser? Our friend IE does cache requests unfortunately...

Comment: yeah, it's in firefox also.. but if the browser was caching the request, wouldn't that mean I wouldn't see the jQuery callback function executing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the jQuery [ajax() function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you can specify the "cache" parameter and set it to false to prevent browser caching.

```
$.ajax({ url: "test.html", cache: false, success: function(){
  // your code here
}});
```